# Gurobi mixed-integer linear programming problem gap information

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I am solving a mixed-integer linear programming (MILP) problem on matlab using the solver gurobi. During the iterations, I see information like:

> Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
>   Best objective 6.076620143590e+02, best bound 6.076620143590e+02, gap 0.0000%

My question is: how can access to the information on the gap? I would like to store it at every iteration in an array. However, if I just call `X = gurobi(model);`, where `model` contains my MILP model, I do not see information on the gap in `X`.

Comment: You might need to calculate it yourself within a [callback](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/callback_codes.html#sec:CallbackCodes).

Comment: @sascha can I do it on Matlab?

Comment: This page can help: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/logging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the information about the gap is already returned by gurobi since version 8. I was using version 7 before and therefore I did not have access to that information. The variable in the returned object that contains the information about the gap is called `mipgap`, it is explained [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/mipgap.html).